ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest - Frameworks/MapboxCommon.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
apple email
ITMS-91056: Invalid privacy manifest - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file from the following path is invalid: “Frameworks/MapboxCommon.framework/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy”. Keys and values in any privacy manifest must be in a valid format. For more details about privacy manifest files,
fixd with me by this steps

yarn add @rnmapbox/maps@10.1.21

in podfile add

$RNMapboxMapsImpl = 'mapbox'


$RNMapboxMapsVersion = '= 10.17.0'

add in target
  pre_install do |installer|
     $RNMapboxMaps.pre_install(installer)
end

add in post_install do |installer|

 $RNMapboxMaps.post_install(installer)


in Info.plist add
  <key>MBXAccessToken</key>
  <string>sk.......</string>  

 <key>NSLocationTemporaryUsageDescriptionDictionary</key>
    <dict>
    <key>LocationAccuracyAuthorizationDescription</key>
   <string>Please enable precise location. Turn-by-turn directions only work when precise location data is available.</string>
   </dict>

delete pods and Podfile.lock

cd ios && pod install --repo-update

